# urlencoded Vs form-data in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, urlencode, multipart

Is there any quick way to determine whether passing data is `urlencoded` or `form-data` (multiparty) data in Node.JS?

Comment: What you're really asking here is how to get the forms enctype, as in either `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the request's `Content-Type` header value: `console.log(req.headers['content-type']);`